# Iterating nested Structure of Maps and Lists

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following `HashMap` `map`, containing the `ArrayList` `content`, containing several `HashMaps`:

```
{
   key1=val1,
   key2=val2,
   // ...
   content=   [
      {
         keyAbc=val10,
         keyDef=val11,
         KeyGhi=val12,
      },
      {
         keyAbc=val13,
         keyDef=val14,
         KeyGhi=val15
      },
      {
         keyAbc=val16,
         keyDef=val17,
         KeyGhi=val18
      }
   ],
   key20=val20,
   // ...
}
```

Now I need to get all keys and values `content`.

---

1. **Getting into the ArrayList**

When I try

```
for(int i=0; i<map.get("content").size(); i++){}
```

it says `cannot find symbol`, as if it doesn't recognize the `ArrayList`.

However, casting it as an ArrayList works:

```
for(int i=0; i<((ArrayList)map.get("content")).size(); i++){}
```

---

2. **Getting into the HashMap**

So within that loop I try:

```
// for(...){
   for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> obj : (((ArrayList)map.get("content")).get(i)){}
}
```

The following error appears:

> for-each not applicable to expression type
>   required: array or java.lang.Iterable
>   found: Object

Casting as a HashMap:

```
// for(...){
   for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> obj : ((HashMap)(ArrayList)map.get("content")).get(i)){}
}
```

Produces that error:

> incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to HashMap

---

So how can I access the contents of `content`?

Comment: You have a problem with your declared types. These type casts are going to be necessary unless you use a proper class for your object. Is this deserialized JSON?

Comment: @ernest_k: Yes, it is.

Comment: @user1170330 can you post the json instead of the jvm inspect of the json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to iterate over the entries of the `Map`, so you should call `entrySet`:

```
for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> obj : ((HashMap)((ArrayList)map.get("content")).get(i)).entrySet() {}
```

To make it more readable, I'd break it into multiple statements. I'd also use the interface types instead of `ArrayList` and `HashMap`.

```
List list = (List) map.get("content");
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Map map = (Map) list.get(i);
    for (Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use more code to have a more human readable version of it and I replace concrete classes with interfaces (you can't be sure that the deserializer will create an `ArrayList` instead of another kind of `List`, same for `Map`) having the following code:

```
List content = (List) map.get("content");
for (Object item : content) {
  Map itemMap = (Map) item;
  for (Map.Entry entry : itemMap.entrySet()) {
     // Doing what you like with entry  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through list which is value content key. I suppose below code is what you are looking for.

```
         for (Map<Object, Object> listEntry : (List<Map<Object, Object>>) map.get("content")) {
        for (Map.Entry innerMapEtry : listEntry.entrySet()) {
            final Object key = innerMapEtry.getKey();
            final Object value = innerMapEtry.getValue();
        }
    }
```